# What's the parametric equations of a hyperbolic dodecahedron?

Tags: parametric, mathematical-modeling, hyperbolic-geometry, computational-geometry, parametrization

I was hoping someone could help me determine explicitly the
parameterized equations in 3D plane geometry (x,y,z) for a hyperbolic dodecahedron, and ideally the other hyperbolic form platonic solids Tetrahedron, Hexahedron [cube], and Icosahedron. I'm modeling them using MathMod and the programming language is in explicit parametric form. I'm not familiar with how to calculate the shapes in this way, but did find the hyperbolic octahedron in it's explicit parametric form, including it's intervals, using the mathworld-wolfram website [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicOctahedron.html], but the formulas weren't included in the other hyperbolic shapes.

How would I go about converting these shapes into this form?

Comment: Look for the work of Igor Rivin. It may have the formulas you need.

Comment: By the way, he himself uses this website! @IgorRivin

Comment: I'm looking into his work, thanks. Actually, I noticed he's the referenced author of the hyperbolic dodecahedron graphic on the cited mathworld page in my OP.

Comment: Does he give also for hyperbolic cube, icosahedron, etc. Is there a link?

Comment: He was referenced in the above mathworld.wolfram link in the OP and for the other hyperbolic shapes in the same site, but he's referenced for their graphical representions not for the parametric equations (of which only the hyperbolic octahedron has listed). "Rivin, I. "Hyperbolic Polyhedra Graphics." http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4558/ "

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work out approximate parametric equations for a hyperbolic tetrahedron.

$x = (2\cos(u) + 2\cos^2(u) - 1)(1 - v)^2$

$y = (2\sin(u) - 2\sin(u)\cos(u))(1 - v)^2$

$z = \cos^3(v)$

Where u $\in$ [-$\pi$, $\pi$] and v $\in$ [0, 1]. Hope this helps.